# Total Space occupied by all the Notes

Tags: evernote

In Evernote, how is it possible to know the total space used by all the notes that I have in my account?

Answer (score 1):

[CalS](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/101233-how-to-find-total-storage-space-i-am-using/) November 4, 2016:

> if Windows go to Tools - Options - General  and click on Open Database folder.  The file with an EXB extension should approximate the size of your EN data base.

[DTLow](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/101233-how-to-find-total-storage-space-i-am-using/) November 4, 2016:

> If you click on About Evernote and press the Option key, you'll get a link to your database folder
>
> You can get the size of the database on your Mac This should be
>   complete, unless you have local notebooks on other computers. I have
>   two accounts 1.86GB and 5.76GB The database for each account is under
>   a number folder for example 123456
>
> Space used on the servers would be similar, but not include local
>   notebooks So it could be less space; however for me, the important
>   number is the space taken up on my computer